# SpotifyR search_spotify command does not appear to search in track names

Tags: r, spotify

I can’t get the SpotifyR package to extract songs which have a specific title using the search_spotify command

I have read the Spotify [developer page](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#category-search) and the Spotifyr package [readme](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spotifyr/spotifyr.pdf).

Reproducible example below:

```
library(spotifyr)

Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = ‘myID’)

Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = ‘myCLIENTSECRET’)

access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()

searchresults <- search_spotify('Zooropa','track')
```

I would expect the results of this to be the Spotify tracks with the title “Zooropa”. This should be 7 results due to the presence of karaoke and tribute songs which include Zooropa in the track title. Instead the results are 16 observations, including every one of the 10 tracks on the Zooropa album, even those not called Zooropa (e.g. Lemon and Babyface).

Since I am searching in the ‘track’ field I don’t understand why I get the extra 9 results.

Answer (score 0):

The spotify api returns the track id's for all of the search results. Zooropa is also an album as well as a song. If you search "Zooropa" inside of Spotify there will be more than 1 result.

Answer (score 0):

Having researched this I have discovered that the spotifyr package does not allow the same search options as the underlying Spotify API. When using the search command in the Spotify API the "type" parameter allows the search to be restricted to tracks (see [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/)). This type parameter cannot currently be used in spotifyr.

However, I have created a workaround which might be useful to others and the code for this is below. Stringdist is used because after I have extracted the data using spotifyr, I need to identify which track names are closest to "Zooropa". I use the jw method but others could be used.

```
library(spotifyr)
library(stringdist)

Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = 'yourID')
Sys.setenv(SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = 'yourclientsecret')

access_token <- get_spotify_access_token()
searchresults <- search_spotify('Zooropa','track')
artists <-searchresults$artists
artists2 <-lapply(artists, function(x) x[,3])
artists3 <-lapply(artists2, function(x) paste(x, collapse=', '))
searchresults$realartist <-as.data.frame(unlist(artists3))
usefuloutput <-cbind(searchresults$id,searchresults$name,searchresults$realartist)
colnames(usefuloutput) <- c("Spotifyid", "Spotifyname","Spotifyartist")
usefuloutput$titlecomparison <-stringdist(usefuloutput[,2],'Zooropa',method="jw")
```